# AD property is System.Byte[] - which Encoding to convert to string?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am reading the displayName property from ActiveDirectory.

On Windows Server 2008, `result.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString()` is the displayName,
while on Windows Server 2012, it returns `System.Byte[]`. Now I have to convert the value using sth like 
`var buffer = result.Properties["displayName"][0];
Encoding.%SomeEncoding%.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`,
but I don't know which Encoding Microsoft chose - UTF, ISO, Default, Local?

By the way, is there a "cheat sheet" on AD properties and their types available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory implements [LDAP v3 and that uses UTF-8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961766.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can read a byte value from AD like this:

`Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])userRow.Properties["mailNickname"][0]);`